# Переменная Диапазона и DataRow

Tags: c#, winforms, view, ado.net

Объясниете, пожалуйста, как OrderDate снчала переменная и сохраняет числа а потом становится строкой. И выводит к тому же дату. Хотя изначально сохраняла "CustomerNo" ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

// Перекресные запросы между таблицами LINQ to DataSet

namespace Joins
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ShopDB = new DataSet();

            ShopDB.ReadXmlSchema(@"D:\ADO.NET\DATA\ShopDbSchema.xml");
            ShopDB.ReadXml(@"D:\ADO.NET\DATA\ShopDbData.xml");

            var customers = ShopDB.Tables["Customers"];
            var orders = ShopDB.Tables["Orders"];

            var inner = from customer in customers.AsEnumerable() // InnerJoin
                        join order in orders.AsEnumerable()
                        on customer["CustomerNo"] equals order["CustomerNo"]
                        select new { Fname = customer["FName"], LName = customer["LName"], OrderDate = order["OrderDate"] };

            var outer = from customer in customers.AsEnumerable() // OuterJoin
                         join order in orders.AsEnumerable()
                         on customer["CustomerNo"] equals order["CustomerNo"] into OrderDate //здесь OrderDate это переменная диапазона
                        select new { Fname = customer["FName"], LName = customer["LName"], OrderDate };  //здесь OrderDate это DataRow
            
                        foreach (var item in inner)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{2:D} {1} {0}", item.LName, item.Fname, item.OrderDate);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));
                        foreach (var item in outer)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{1} {0}", item.LName, item.Fname);
                            foreach (var item2 in item.OrderDate) // теперь используя item из внешнего циклаitem.OrderDate??
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\t" + item2["OrderDate"]);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }

            }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Тут все просто

В первом случае вы создаёте новый объект
и заполняете его поля

```
new { Fname = customer["FName"], LName = customer["LName"], OrderDate = order["OrderDate"] };
```

при этом явно указываете чему равно поле в новом объекте `OrderDate = order["OrderDate"]`

Во втором случае вы создаете объект

```
new { Fname = customer["FName"], LName = customer["LName"], OrderDate };
```

данная запись эквивалентна

```
new { Fname = customer["FName"], LName = customer["LName"], OrderDate = OrderDate};
```

где
`OrderDate` это результат

```
join order in orders.AsEnumerable()
on customer["CustomerNo"] equals order["CustomerNo"]
```

или

```
OrderDate = order // это псевдоним в данном случае
```

То есть вы вполне можете переписать второй случай на эквивалентный

```
var outer = from customer in customers.AsEnumerable() // OuterJoin
                     join order in orders.AsEnumerable()
                     on customer["CustomerNo"] equals order["CustomerNo"] 
                    select new { Fname = customer["FName"], LName = customer["LName"], OrderDate = order};
```

Думаю теперь понятно почему у вас в первом случае это значение поля во втором это вся запись.